# Multicast group member priority

Tags: udp, multicast, winsock2

I have come across a problem whose specifics are as follows:

I have a multicast group in which i have observed that, a udp packet sent by a member in a multicast group is received by other membes based on the sequence in which they have joined the group.

for eg: If server1,2,3,4 join groups in respective sequence then if a packet is received in the group it is received first by 1 then 2 and so on.

I have checked this behaviour via some test applications aswell.

I am using Winsock2 ,Please let me know if their is sequencing at kernel level and to priortize the group members if possible.

Comment: You can only send to one group at a time, whilst you can subscribe to multiple groups on one socket.  The question is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Multicasts are received by members in the order the multicasts arrive at the member hosts. A multicast datagram is sent once, not multiple times, so it can't have a significantly different arrival time per member. Arrival time has nothing to do with join time: it has more to do with the delay in the respective paths, number of routers, etc. If all the members were on the end of identical pieces of wire they would all get the multicast at the same time.

Having said all that, if you're concerned about the order that multicasts are received in, and you think you need to re-prioritize them, you're doing something seriously wrong. Multicasts in their nature are UDP datagrams which may be received out of order, multiple times, or not at all.

Comment: Yes its true that a datagram is sent just once, but what i am trying to find out now is whether or not it depends on the Multicast Routing Table created whenever a member joins the group.

Comment: @RohitJ So your question was incomplete. If there is such a table, it only exists in a router. You can't see inside a router to see how it is implemented, and even if you could it could change tomorrow with the next firmware update. You shouldn't be relying on this sort of thing, even slightly.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete question. Thats what i am worried about, i dont know what i have to do at application level to overcome this problem.

Comment: @RohitJ I've told you. Stop regarding it as a problem. It isn't. Multicasts get to the members, or not, in any order, or not. Nothing you  can do about it.

Comment: again sorry for insufficient information i forget to mentioned one thing that all the multicast listeners are on the same machine (ie. three different instances of the same application are joining to multicast group from the same machine itself). To be more specific and isolating the problem area, we tried running the UDP multicast sender(1 sender) and listeners(3 listeners) on the same machine. Yet we could observe the above mentioned behaviour on 7 out of 10 times.

Comment: @RohitJ Still nothing you can do about it. If your system depends on some order, or simultaneous delivery, in any way, you will just have to remove that dependency.